# Why users who are members of Office 365 group can view the Group inside their outlook, while owner only can not

Tags: sharepoint-online, active-directory, groups, outlook, office-365-groups

I have created 2 Office 365 groups:-

1. GroupA
2. GroupB

And I added user1 as the owner of GroupA, and as the owner and member of GroupB. now when user1 accesses his outlook, the user will only see GroupB under the Groups sections. So why is this happening? can I conclude that the owner alone will not show the group under the Groups section inside outlook? and the user needs to be a member also?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, this seems to be the way it was designed to work. The user needs to be a member.

Comment: @JoelRodrigues that looks a bot wired .. is it correct?

Comment: yes it's a bit weird but seems to be by design....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design from Microsoft. The behavior is a bit strange as we need to add the user as Owner and Member both.

I have faced a similar issue in the past and when I dug up, I observed that when we check the Manage Groups under outlook, you will find the group under the Owner section.

Consider Below Scenario:

I created an O365 Group named HyBrid, added user1 as both owner and member. I created another O365 Group named MembersGroup and added user1 as the member.

When I check the Manage Groups Section in the outlook for user1, the HyBrid group appears in the Owners and MembersGroup appears in the Members.

**Owners Section:**
[image]

**Members Section:**
[image]

**Note:** Similar behavior has been observed by other user as well. Kindly check the comment under [O365 Group not visible](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-groups/office-365-groups-not-visible-in-outlook-client/m-p/1359894/highlight/true#M6177) thread

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that how it works from the beginning, if you need to let the owners see the group at the OWA or the outlook client, you need to add them both **Owner and Members**.

I know it's weird, but this is how it works :p